# Sprite jumping way too high

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, platform

Earlier, we fixed the lag of the code and before, the game made the sprite lag. We fixed that, but this time it keeps making the sprite fly way too high and out of the screen not coming back down... What can we do so that the sprite(poppy) does not jump so high?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class Poppy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self): #making the player
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.image = pygame.image.load('POPPY.png')
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.grav = .5
       self.y_vel = 5
       self.jumping = False

   def jump_update(self): #checking the jumps
       if self.jumping:
           self.y_vel += self.grav
           self.rect.y += self.y_vel

   def jump(self): #the jump initializer
       if not self.jumping:
           self.y_vel = -50
           self.jumping = True

   def keys(self): #the keys
       key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       dist = 5
       if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
           self.rect.x += dist # move right
       elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
           self.rect.x -= dist

   def collide_check(self, platform_list): #check if it hit the ground or the platforms
       for blocks in platform_list:
           if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, blocks) == True:
               self.rect.y = blocks.top

       if self.rect.y >= 600-self.rect.height:              # BALL HITS TOP AND BOTTOM
           self.y_vel = 0
           self.rect.y = 600 - self.rect.height
           self.jumping = False

   def move(self):
       self.rect.y += self.y_vel

   def draw(self, surface):
       surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.image = pygame.image.load('levoneplatform.png')
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

 def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Menu():
   def __init__(self):
       self.background_image = pygame.image.load('menu.png').convert_alpha()

   def update(self):
       screen.blit(self.background_image, [0,0])


class LevOne():
   def __init__(self):

       self.background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()


       platforms_one = [ (200,300),
                       (50,500),
                       (550,650),
                       (300,200),
                       (120,100)
                  ]
       for k,v in platforms_one:
           platform = Platform()
           enemy = Enemy()
           platform.rect.x = k
           enemy.rect.x = k
           platform.rect.y = v
           enemy.rect.y = v - 44
           platform_list.add(platform)
           enemy_list.add(enemy)

   def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.background_image, [0, 0])

class LevTwo():
   def __init__(self):

       self.background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()

       platforms_two = platforms_two = [ (300,400),
                       (500,500),
                       (100,300),
                       (300,100),
                  ]

       for k,v in platforms_two:
           platform = Platform()
           enemy = Enemy()
           platform.rect.x = k
           enemy.rect.x = k
           platform.rect.y = v
           enemy.rect.y = v - 44
           platform_list.add(platform)
           enemy_list.add(enemy)

   def update(self):
       screen.blit(self.background_image, [0,0])


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
Poppy = Poppy()
Menu = Menu()
LevOne = LevOne()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level = 1

while True:
  clock.tick(60)

  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()
      elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == K_SPACE:
              Poppy.jump()

  Menu.update()
  if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
       x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
       if x >= 544.86 and x <= 700.86 and y <= 385.02 and y >= 340.03:
           level = 1

  if level == 1:


      Poppy.keys()
      Poppy.move()

      LevOne.update()


      Poppy.draw(screen)
      platform_list.draw(screen)
      enemy_list.draw(screen)

      pygame.display.update()

  if level == 2:

      second_lives = 3

      LevTwo.update()
      Poppy.keys()
      Poppy.move()

      platform_list.draw(screen)
      enemy_list.draw(screen)
      Poppy.draw(screen)

  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set the gravity at 0.5 units/second^2, but jump at a velocity of -50 units/second; it will take nearly two minutes for the character to start falling again!

Either increase the gravity, or decrease the velocity of the jump to something like -3.

EDIT:

Call this function somewhere in your `move()` or `update()` function:

```
def jump_update(self): #checking the jumps
   if self.jumping:
       self.y_vel += self.grav
       self.rect.y += self.y_vel
```

Right now it's not being used.

Comment: Thank you but it keeps moving up and won't stop. What could I do?

Comment: @Angela I looked at your code and there were a few mistakes. I edited my answer to include one of those. Don't forget to make sure you are checking collisions properly; I couldn't get the player to land on platforms. You may also want to stop adding gravity when `self.y_vel > 12` to keep the falling from becoming too fast.